# Why doesn't my Content Hub script log DEBUG messages?

Tags: content-hub, content-hub-scripting

I have an Action Script I've created in Content Hub and it has various calls to log messages:

```
MClient.Logger.Debug("Running script");

MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.ExecutionSource: {Context.ExecutionSource}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.ExecutionType: {Context.ExecutionType}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.TargetId: {Context.TargetId}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.TargetType: {Context.TargetType}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.PropertyBag: {Context.PropertyBag}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.ExecutionEvent: {Context.ExecutionEvent}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.Target: {Context.Target}");
MClient.Logger.Info($"Context.TriggeringUserId: {Context.TriggeringUserId}");

var targetItem = await MClient.Entities.GetAsync(Context.TargetId.Value);
MClient.Logger.Info($"targetItem: {targetItem}");
```

But only the `Info` and above log entries are showing in the View Logs area:
[image: Log entries]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the **Minimum log level** on your script before you save/build/publish it:

[image: Setting Minimum log level]

## Warning

This setting is reset every time you edit a script, so you will need to change it again every time you want to use a logging level more verbose than `INFO`.